# Records getting rejected in HP Vertica While Copying

Tags: vertica

I am trying to load a segmented table in HP Vertica through `COPY DIRECT` from a pipe separated text file.

```
COPY CSI.MKT_RSRCH_AGG_ALL FROM '/opt/vertica/CSI/MKT_RSRCH_AGG_ALL.txt' DELIMITER '|' NULL '' DIRECT;
```

Result

```
 Rows Loaded 
-------------
      582006

dbadmin=> select get_num_rejected_rows();

 get_num_rejected_rows 
-----------------------
                  6046
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing the data to be rejected.

All of my dimensions are defined `NOT NULL`.

Can I check any logs/info for the rejected records.

Comment: Is there any reason that you're using `DIRECT` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by verifying the integrity of the data. Then, I would send any rejected rows to a file. You can [specify this](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#18519.htm) in your `COPY` command:

```
COPY CSI.MKT_RSRCH_AGG_ALL 
FROM '/opt/vertica/CSI/MKT_RSRCH_AGG_ALL.txt' 
DELIMITER '|' 
NULL ''
REJECTED DATA '/path/to/rejected/data'
DIRECT;
```

If you haven't already, I would recommend that you start using stream names to identify the process:

```
COPY ... DIRECT STREAM NAME 'My stream name';
```

You can than easily monitor the stream:

```
SELECT * FROM v_monitor.load_streams WHERE stream_name = 'My stream name';
```

**Documentation**

- [Checking COPY Metrics](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#12067.htm)
- [Specifying a Rejected Data File (`REJECTED DATA`)](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#18519.htm)
- [`COPY` Exception and Rejected Data Files](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#18520.htm)
- [`COPY`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#1668.htm)